# Magento Custom Category Layout on search results?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-view

I've activated a custom design layout on a category, which loads up a different product view page for all the products within that category. It works well, but when searching for a product and then clicking on a product within that category, the custom layout isn't loaded and it falls back to the default layout.

Is there a way to change the product view shown on a search result or load the product view based on it being in that category?

Comment: How Custom layout on category page change the layout on product view page? Search page or category page using different  configuration files.

Comment: I used this method to change the product view dependent on which category the product was in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667676/how-to-display-category-custom-design-layout-in-product-view-page